# sort audio files from photo files

Tags: linux, terminal, powershell, organizer-software, file-organization

I am trying to help an older family member sort through their files.

What I would like to do is look through all the sub directories and make separate folders with the filenames.

example:

```
root > folder_01
     folder_01 may contain .mov .jpg .jpeg files
```

Inside folder_01 I would like to make separate folders with

```
root > folder_01 > mov
root > folder_01 > jpg
root > folder_01 > jpeg
```

the same for `folder_02`, `folder_03` and so forth.

I know this is a complicated task for Linux terminal but maybe even a Linux or Windows program can accomplish this.

Please post if you can help with recommendation or if you need more info I will try to explain better.

Almost willing to do anything then sort through these files for days, that's why I am posting on here.

Comment: use `mkdir -p` to create folders, `mv *.jpg jpg` to move files; and `find -type d -exec youscript.sh '{}' \;` if you have many folders.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script should do what you want (tested under Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10)

```
# Move-FileType.ps1
$Extensions = @('.mov','.jpg','.jpeg')
Get-ChildItem -Directory /root/folder_?? | ForEach-Object {
  ForEach ($Ext in $Extensions) {
    $DestPath = Join-Path $_.FullName $Ext.Trim('.')
    If (!(Test-Path $DestPath)) {mkdir $DestPath|Out-Null}
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -File -Filter "*$Ext" | 
      Move-Item -Destination $DestPath -WhatIf
  }
}
```